# HTMLInputElement event.target.value outputting a string event though it is a range element (typescript)

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

**Issue:**

```
const exampleNumberType: number = 0;
<input type="range" onChange={
   (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => exampleNumberType = event.target.value
}/>
```

In typescript, the above code will throw an error because the type of event.target.value is 'string', but since it is input from a range event, it should be of type number (since range elements are used for selecting numbers, not strings).

Obviously you could use `parseInt()` or something similar to convert the value and make it conform to the type that you will need, but there is a more elegant solution (see answer below)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the `event.target.value` string to a number using standard javascript methods, but I think I found a more elegant solution:

**My Answer:**

Thanks to [this documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlinputelement.html#value) I discovered is that there are methods of the 'event.target' object which will return the value as either a number or, if you wanted it, as a Date...

`event.target.valueAsNumber`

`event.target.valueAsDate`

So the new, code, with no type errors will look like this:

```
const exampleNumberType: number = 0;
<input type="range" onChange={
   (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => exampleNumberType = event.target.valueAsNumber
}/>
```